# Drag and fling map

Tags: java, android

**Hello**,
I am trying to implement dynamic map (View) into my application and I need to make it's movement behave like Google Map has. So It has to do both, scroll and fling. (I have reasons for not using the actual Google Maps).

**At First time**, I handled dragging and flinging of map by it's `Scroll`. But it jittered, because void `View.setScrollX(int)` can't have parameter of float and so it isn't smooth enough.

**At Second**, I tried `Translation` for moving of the map, but even when dragging alone was working and fling alone was working, together it did strange behaviour on fling.

*My question is:* How to make `Scroll` and `Fling` work together well? I will be glad of every advice or snipped of code :)

This is the second solution:

ImageView img;
    String msg = "My LOG";

```
float firstPosX = 0;
float firstPosY = 0;

int touchCount;

FlingAnimation flingAnimX;
FlingAnimation flingAnimY;

GestureDetector gestureDetector;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getApplicationContext(), mGestureListener);

    img.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            touchCount = event.getPointerCount();

            //Stops Fling, so on the new touch it dont continue
            if (flingAnimX != null) {
                flingAnimX.cancel();
            }
            if (flingAnimY != null) {
                flingAnimY.cancel();
            }

            if (touchCount == 1) {
                float deltaPosX = 0;
                float deltaPosY = 0;

                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    firstPosX = event.getX();
                    firstPosY = event.getY();
                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                    deltaPosX = -firstPosX + event.getX();
                    deltaPosY = -firstPosY + event.getY();

                    img.setTranslationX(deltaPosX + img.getTranslationX());
                    img.setTranslationY(deltaPosY + img.getTranslationY());
                }
            }
            gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

            return true;
        }
    });
}

GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener mGestureListener = new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                           float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        if (touchCount == 1) {
            flingAnimX = new FlingAnimation(img, DynamicAnimation.TRANSLATION_X)
                    .setStartVelocity(velocityX);
            flingAnimX.start();
            flingAnimY = new FlingAnimation(img, DynamicAnimation.TRANSLATION_Y)
                    .setStartVelocity(velocityY);
            flingAnimY.start();
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: I figured out the solution. Instead of onFling method, the best way to achieve panning + fling is via VelocityTracker.